# Help Debug KKT Conditions with Slack Variables

Tags: lagrange-multiplier, karush-kuhn-tucker

Following page 118 of [this](http://adl.stanford.edu/aa222/Lecture_Notes_files/chapter5_constrainopt.pdf), I tried to solve a simple problem, but it appears to give me solutions that aren't feasible. What am I doing wrong?

The problem I want to solve is,
\begin{align}
\text{extrem}\ \ &x(x+1)(x-1) \\
\text{s.t.}\ \  &x \ge 0
\end{align}

My Lagrangian and the derivatives become, including my slack variable $s$,
\begin{align}
\mathcal{L} &= x(x+1)(x-1) + \lambda(x - s^2) = 0 \\
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \mathcal{L} &= 3x^2 -1 + \lambda = 0 \\
\frac{\partial}{\partial \lambda} \mathcal{L} &= x - s^2  = 0\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial s} \mathcal{L} &= -2 s\lambda = 0
\end{align}

Solving these,
\begin{align}
0 &= (s\lambda)^2 \\
  &= x \lambda^2 \\
  &= x (3x^2 -1)^2
\end{align}

This gives 3 roots $ x = 0, \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} $. The negative one doesn't satisfy the constraint. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Is my problem that I am implicitly (and inappropriately) allowing $ s $ to be imaginary?

Comment: As with Lagrange multipliers, the KKT conditions give that conditions that $(x,s,\lambda)$ must satisfy, It does **not** say that all $(x,s,\lambda)$ that satisfy the conditions are solutions.

Comment: Shouldn't any $ (x, s, \lambda) $ that satisfy the conditions be a feasible solution? The one I found is **not** feasible because its negative.

Comment: How can a negative $x$ satisfy the conditions? You cannot let $s$ be complex!

Comment: Okay. That's what I was thinking. I just need to be careful to not let anything go complex. Thanks. If you answer, I'll accept it

Comment: You should have $x \ge 0$ rather than $x>0$ above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When solving nonlinear systems of equations, you need to check for spurious solutions (or keep extremely careful track of what range of values the different expressions are allowed to attain, and how irreversible operations like squaring both sides affects these.) In this case, you cannot take $x=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$ since $s$ must be real.

Although it doesn't affect your solution, you also made a few algebra mistakes: first, in the $x$ derivative; you should get $3x^2-1+\lambda=0$.

Next, when you substitute in for $\lambda^2$, somehow the second power disappeared; you should get
$$0 = x(1-3x^2)^2.$$

Comment: Ah. yeah. I was copying off my paper. Thanks for catching them. I think I found a good way to avoid the $ s $ is real problem. If I substitute $ s^2 $ for x instead, then s is maintained real throughout.